# Retrieve all Teams that User is on

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Question**: How do I retrieve all Teams that a User is on?

My Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams, :uniq => true
  has_many :rosterplayers
  has_many :rosters, -> { uniq } ,  :through => :rosterplayers
end

class Roster < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rosterplayers
  has_many :users, -> { uniq }, through: :rosterplayers
end

class Rosterplayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :roster
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :roster_id }
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  # user is the creator of the team
  belongs_to :user 

  # Roster.roster_master(team) is the team's master (full) roster
  has_many :rosters
end
```

- A user can have many Teams (be the 'owner' of but not necessarily be 'on' those teams).
- A user is on
  the "master" Roster of many teams.

**Attempt**:
I tried to grab all the master rosters in the database:

```
# User class:

def teams_on
  # All the rosters the user is on.
  r = Roster.includes(:rosterplayers).where(rosterplayers: { user_id: self.id })

  # Get only master rosters.
  m = r.where(master: true)
end
```

I'm stuck where to go from here (I'm sure there is a better approach anyways).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer after searching a bit more:

[Retrieve all posts where the given user has commented, Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004150/retrieve-all-posts-where-the-given-user-has-commented-ruby-on-rails?rq=1)

All I have to do is add this to the User model:

```
has_many :team_enrollments, :through => :rosters, :source => :team

def teams_on
  self.team_enrollments
end
```